# SoapUI 5.6.0 fails to install on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: installation, soapui, ubuntu-20.04

Execution of the SoapUI-x64-5.6.0.sh script on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS causes the following failure:

```
Starting Installer ...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Container
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:68)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(ConsoleScreenExecutor.java:24)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.java:6)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:88)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:57)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:62)
An error occurred:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Container
Error log: /tmp/install4jError9197831081773222366.log
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Container
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:68)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(ConsoleScreenExecutor.java:24)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.java:6)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:88)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:57)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:62)
```

I have the OpenJDK Java version 11 installed:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to execute the SoapUI-x64-5.6.0.sh script using the following command:

```
./SoapUI-x64-5.6.0.sh -J-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Comment: that did help to run the installation, but now the software itself won't start..

Answer (score 0):

Just update your openjdk version.
Follow these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error because all online tutorials adviced to use sudo for installer execution. Tried without sudo and it worked for me